# Generating the Path for Chromedriver Using AbsPath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, os.path

I am trying to set up a driver using chromedriver.  If I supply the entire path name it works fine.  But if I supply a string generated by os.path.abspath I get the  "'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH" error.  Why is that, and is there a way to generate the path without hardcoding the entire path to my executeable?

```
my_executable_path = "env//bin//chromedriver.exe"    

absolute_path = str(os.path.abspath(my_executable_path)).replace("/", "//")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= absolute_path,
                                  options=chrome_options)    
return(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a python package `webdriver-manager`. You can install it using pip : `pip install webdriver-manager` 
Once the package is installed, you won't need to specify the chromedriver path or download `chromdriver.exe`
 Just use the below lines in your script and the plugin will identify the version of chrome browser installed in your system:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("google.com")
```